# If I've done multiple checkrides, when is my next flight review due?

Tags: faa-regulations

Currently, I hold a Commercial Pilot Certificate, the question is when is my next flight review due?

Certification Dates are as follows:

Private Pilot - 02/05/2017
IRA - 11/10/2017
Commercial Pilot - 02/01/2018

It's supposed that a checkride counts as a Flight Review, so every checkride would add 24 calendar months to the initial?

Or it's just 24 calendar months after the last one?

Answer (score 5):

The due date of your next Flight Review is based on your last check ride (your Commercial Check Ride). You will be required to complete a Flight Review (or equivalent) by the last day of February 2020.

**§61.56   Flight review:** (emphasis is mine)

> (a) Except as provided in paragraphs (b) and (f) of this section, a flight review consists of a minimum of 1 hour of flight training and 1 hour of ground training. The review must include:
>
> (1) A review of the current general operating and flight rules of part 91 of this chapter; and
>
> (2) A review of those maneuvers and procedures that, at the discretion of the person giving the review, are necessary for the pilot to demonstrate the safe exercise of the privileges of the pilot certificate.
>
> (b) Glider pilots may substitute a minimum of three instructional flights in a glider, each of which includes a flight to traffic pattern altitude, in lieu of the 1 hour of flight training required in paragraph (a) of this section.
>
> (c) Except as provided in paragraphs (d), (e), and (g) of this section, no person may act as pilot in command of an aircraft **unless, since the beginning of the 24th calendar month before the month in which that pilot acts as pilot in command,** that person has—
>
> (1) Accomplished a flight review given in an aircraft for which that pilot is rated by an authorized instructor and
>
> (2) A logbook endorsed from an authorized instructor who gave the review certifying that the person has satisfactorily completed the review.
>
> (d) **A person who has, within the period specified in paragraph (c) of this section, passed any of the following need not accomplish the flight review required by this section:**
>
> (1) A pilot proficiency check or **practical test conducted by an examiner**, an approved pilot check airman, or a U.S. Armed Force, **for a pilot certificate,** rating, or operating privilege.
>
> (2) A practical test conducted by an examiner for the issuance of a flight instructor certificate, an additional rating on a flight instructor certificate, renewal of a flight instructor certificate, or reinstatement of a flight instructor certificate.